# tee stderr to file (csh/tcsh shell)

Tags: redirect, csh, tcsh, tee

How to redirect the STDEER to a file and both STDOUT & STDERR still show on screen?

I found many method on web, but they not work on csh/tcsh shell.
However, my command cannot run at "bash shell".

I know something like below :

(command > /dev/null) >& stderr.log

But this will mask the screen display.

Comment: But I only want to redirect STDERR to file, NOT both STDOUT & STDERR.

Comment: My apologies, I misread.

Answer (score 2):

`tcsh`'s IO redirection options are redirecting stdout and stderr simultaneously or just stdout.

One option is to redirect stdout to `/dev/tty` and then dup stderr into stdout and `tee` it.

```
% (command > /dev/tty) |& tee stderr.log
```

Note that this will always write to the console, even if used in a script which you then pipe somewhere else.

You can call other shells from inside tcsh, so it's worth mentioning what they can do.

Bourne-compatible shells can only pipe stdout, but do have syntax for manipulating file descriptors, by using a third file descriptor as temporary storage we can swap stdout and stderr. The sequence `3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 3>&-` accomplishes this and then closes file descriptor 3.

```
$ (command 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | tee stderr.log) 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 3>&-
```

Bash and some other shells like zsh support process substitution, which lets you use a command as a source `<(...)` or destination `>(...)`.

```
$ command 2> >(tee stderr.log)
```

If you don't mind rants, http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt and http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot have some decent information about some of the rough edges of (t)csh quoting, redirection, conditionals, and aliases. Some of the information about specific bugs is long out of date, however.